# ANTS Profiler: Change the default browser?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, red-gate-ants

I cannot find this information anywhere.

Within Visual Studio I'm using the ANTS Profiler add-on.  It always launches IE. My default browser is Firefox. I cannot find a setting anywhere where I can change the default.

Can someone help?

Comment: Is your operating system default browser FireFox or the VS 2008 default browser? If you right click on an aspx file the context menu has a Browse With menu item.  This is where you set the default browser for Visual Studio.

Comment: Yeah its set to Chrome currently.  I tried changing it to Firefox but got the same results.

Comment: Are you trying to profile a web app? If so, when you debug your application from VS, which browser gets launched? Which version of ANTS are you running?

Comment: Yes its a web app. IE gets launched from VS. Profiler v5.1.0.14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to set the your browser default within Visual Studio. Instead you can use PowerShell to accomplish this. See the following for details:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToChangeTheDefaultBrowserInVisualStudioProgrammaticallyWithPowerShellAndPossiblyPokeYourselfInTheEye.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, at the moment, ANTS can only start IE, rather than your current default browser. For now, you would have to use the workaround of starting the profiling session, and then starting whichever browser you want to use manually.

Answer (score 0):

You could always try messing with the wild-and-crazy [Image File Execution Options](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greggm/archive/2005/02/21/377663.aspx) setting in the registry.  If ANTS will only start IE, then you can set firefox.exe to be the "debugger" for iexplore.exe.  Following the steps in the link above, you could add a key for iexplore.exe and set the "Debugger" string value to the full path for firefox.exe.  Then, whenever anything tries to launch IE, Firefox will start instead.

Just remember to remove the key when you're finished!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way now, in version 8 you can choose the browser that you want to launch.